# Angular2 Oninit with AfterViewInit

Tags: angular, asynchronous, initialization

```
  ngOnInit() {
          this.getPointsOfInterest(this.lat, this.lon).subscribe(
(response) => {this.data = response.json();
                this.lat = this.data.lat;
                this.lon = this.data.lon;
                  },
 (error) => console.log(error)
}

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    var src = { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lon }; 
    var map = L.map('map', { zoomControl: false }).setView(src, 14);
}
```

The data has not been uploaded yet in ngAfterViewInit this.lat and  this.lon = undefined.

How to solve?

Comment: Please share more code instead of comments.

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` is invoked after view is initialized, not necessarily data from server is received. data should be accessed only after response from server is received.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could subscribe to observe the output of your request, and then do what you need to do with the data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get('/app/data.json')
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.data= data;
            // actions with data
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngAfterViewInit` does not work the way you think it does. Angular calls this method once it initializes child components and the current component view.

At this point, your async request may or may not have finished and returned with data. You cannot assume it will always be ready within `ngAfterViewInit`

You should use your data within subscribe methods.

For more info, check this url: [Life cycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)